# Do... While creates infinite loop when a variable instead of int is char in c

Tags: c

Here is the code that causes the problem:

```
int n;
do{
printf(/*Message that tells the user to enter an int*/);
}while(scanf("%d", &n) != 1);//Checks that the variable is an int; if not restarts the do while loop and waits for the user input again (at least it's what it's supposed to do)
```

when the user enters an int, the code continues normally. But if they enter something else, this is repeated infinitely:

```
    printf(/*Message that tells the user to enter an int*/);
```

without waiting for the user input again. I don't know what to do now, this problem is driving me crazy (i'm a newbie, so if the question ends up being stupid, i won't be surprised), any help would be welcome! thank you in advance!

Comment: When the user enters something that doesn't jive with the requested format specifier, the `while` condition trips. Now consider what is *still* in the input stream, repeatedly failing, and repeatedly remaining, with each subsequent invoke to `scanf` .

Comment: @WhozCraig jive -> jibe